# WP Plugin confirm button not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to fix a problem with my website. I am using a plugin for the store and the confirm button during checkout isn't working. I've tried adding in a jquery script of my own that hides and shows what is supposed to happen but the button still does nothing.

```
    $("#checkout-next").click(function ()
        {
             if ($("#shopping-cart-form").css("display") = 'none')
            {
                $("#shopping-cart-form").css({ display: "block", float: ""});
                $("#shopping-cart").css({ display: "none", float: "left"});
            }
        });
```

Comment: How is jQuery imported?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have a missing equal sign in your condition:

```
$("#shopping-cart-form").css("display") == 'none'
                                        ^
```

And you have 2 errors on your page also:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function 
$("#checkout-next").click(function ()
TypeError: active_items is undefined
var is_active = active_items.hasOwnProperty( $checkout_item ) && active_items[$c...
```